# news ticker jquery plugin problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, news-ticker

i have a problem in 'News ticker' jquery plugin.
when i mouseover the news titles their link is something like [object object]

here i put my code:

http://bitcont.com/test/news-ticker/

what is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong; I think there's a bug in the plugin itself. In runTicker, The plugin is printing out

```
// [object object]
tickerData.newsAttributes[tickerData.currentItem]
```

when it should be printing out either

```
// cached value of link.attr("href")
tickerData.newsLinks[tickerData.currentItem]
```

or

```
// cached value of the href HTML attribute
tickerData.newsAttributes[tickerData.currentItem].href
```

Patch it, and then maybe let the developer know?

Comment: thank you.i take a look at the plugin code and changed newsAttributes[newsItemCounter] = linkAttributes; (line 129) to newsAttributes[newsItemCounter] = linkAttributes[attrs[0].nodeName]; and it is ok now.i also sent a message to developer to report bug and its solution.